# PHP- Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '('

Tags: php, regex

I am checking browser agent and version using preg match. but i found error while i update my php version 5.3 to 5.4

```
preg_match( '/Mozilla/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/',$HTTP_USER_AGENT,$log_version)
```

have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: escape backslash, because it's a special regex operator `'/Mozilla\/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/'`

Comment: i have same issue in preg_match('/Netscape([0-9])/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/',$HTTP_USER_AGENT,$log_version1).  so that i need to add \ before second / like this preg_match('/Netscape([0-9])\/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/',$HTTP_USER_AGENT,$log_version1)

Comment: Read about [regular expression pattern delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Your `regex` contains a delimiter in the middle of the pattern.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas there is no backslash (`\ `) in the `regex` posted in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `\` (backslash) before second `/`(forwardslash) to escape it

```
preg_match( '/Mozilla\/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/',$HTTP_USER_AGENT,$log_version);

preg_match('/Netscape([0-9])\/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/',$HTTP_USER_AGENT,$log_version1);
```

***Note:-*** Any `/` in between starting and ending `/`(delementer) in `preg_match()` need to be escaped to make it run fine.